For each selenium request Google Chrome Browser generates 4 MB Browser Metrics file
I am using "Chrome for Testing" browser to execute my Jasmine / Selenium Test cases.
While executing the test case, when browser start creating BrowserMetrics-XXXXXXXX-XXXX.pma
files. Due to which space is getting used in GB.
Is there any option to open "Chrome for Testing" browser by disabling the BrowserMetrics file generation?
